# PyCharm does not recognize objects from Pyomo package

Tags: pycharm, pyomo

I've been using PyCharm and Pyomo together for a while now, and for some reason PyCharm does not recognize any of the types imported from `pyomo.environ`. It's rather infuriating to have so many red lines all over my code that runs perfectly fine.

As a simple example from a project I just created that only has this file,

```
from pyomo.environ import *

location_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
distance_dict = {('a', 'b'): 1000,
                 ('a', 'c'): 1500,
                 ('b', 'c'): 2000,
                 ('a', 'c'): 1000,
                 ('c', 'a'): 1500,
                 ('c', 'b'): 2000,
                 ('a', 'a'): 0,
                 ('b', 'b'): 0,
                 ('c', 'c'): 0}

m = ConcreteModel()

m.locations = Set(initialize=location_list)
m.dist = Param(m.locations, m.locations, initialize=distance_dict)
m.x = Var(m.locations, m.locations, within=Binary)
```

This throws unresolved reference warnings for `ConcreteModel`, `Set`, `Param`, `Var`, and `Binary`, in addition to the "Unused import statement" of the first line. I created a virtual environment for this project, in which this is the only file, installed Pyomo, and set it as the current project interpreter. As other posts have suggested, I closed and reopened PyCharm. Still, I get these "errors," and of course the code runs without issue.

Is there any way to fix this? I would like to use PyCharm, but the slew of false warnings stress me out so much that I can't deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

Environments have trouble with star imports `*`. If you import the items that you need explicitly, you won't have this problem, e.g. `from pyomo.environ import (Constraint, ConcreteModel)`.